# I'm starving to death

Tags: might-and-magic-x-legacy

I am on my way to the final boss of the entire game. (faceless)

I took the boat, of which there is no return.

But now I'm starving to death!

I cannot rest, as I've no food; I cannot cure anything as I'm feeble minded.
And I cannot travel back to any inn for more food... What do I do? It's a very long time since I did a proper save as opposed to auto/quick save.

Without my mage, I cannot defend my team or heal. And my people are 70% weaker. I can still hit a lot on the boss, but I have to get 4 fragments, and once someone dies, it's over. I have the resurrection in my party, which I have used, but she's on cool down.
I have killed my mage off to resurrect, to get rid of feeble mind, then dispel all magic. But without food, they become weak the next move... So I'm still weakened with no way to rest between any encounter.

It would be fun to do the final boss, but I cannot in my weakened form, for all my trying.

Does anyone know how to acquire food? Trainer/cheat/in-game? Or any other combos I can do to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

you can use Windows to help you. In the save game folder, right click on the quicksave file, select 'Restore old versions' and hopefully you'll see previous versions of the file that are more recent than your last non-quicksave file.

Comment: I never did try this. I got a trainer working in the end, and set my food count to 999. However from my understanding, Restore old versions, only shows files from backups.

Comment: not backups. It's created whenever a 'restore point' is created which happens more frequently than you'd think. It happens when you install stuff, and depending on Windows version, by default it could also be scheduled to run when you start the computer up, and nightly (midnight) (if the computer is up).  The only problem you may have is if the default allocated space is too small or if you did some massive changes, etc.

Comment: @Doomsknight you should post your solution as the answer